# How do I get Mint Menu in my Gnome Flashback panel in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel

I tried installing the Mint Menu package following [these instructions](http://linuxg.net/how-to-install-mintmenu-5-5-2-on-ubuntu-14-04-trusty-tahr-and-linux-mint-17-qiana/). However, when I get to the step of actually installing, I get these errors:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mintmenu
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mintmenu : Depends: python-mate-menu but it is not installable
            Depends: libmatepanelapplet but it is not installable
            Depends: mate-menus but it is not installable
            Depends: gir1.2-mate-panel but it is not installable
            Depends: mozo but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

From what I see on the web, it seems like it should be possible to install Mint Menu, but maybe I've been misled.

Can I get Mint Menu to appear on my Gnome Panel in Gnome Flashback?

If not, is there an alternative menu that approximates the look, feel, and functionality of the Mint Menu that will work on my system?

Comment: given the name "mint menu" and the fact "mate" was mentioned - maybe you need to be using mate-panel rather than gnome-panel?

Comment: @fossfreedom, please see my updated question.