# How can I install ubuntu 20.04 packages to 21.10?

Tags: package-management, upgrade

For example MSSQL supports only up to 20.04 version of ubuntu, zabbix too. I'm new to linux and installed last version of ubuntu instead of LTS one, don't want to reinstall system because of it.

Comment: FYI:  You didn't say if you're talking about a desktop or server install (SQL implies server to me), but you can re-install Ubuntu Desktop without losing config/datafiles & additional packages... ie. I have QA-test installs where I jump around regularly (21.04 back to 20.04.3, to 21.10, will go back to 20.04.4 next as I use boxes I use for QA-test installs; my datafiles not being touched & *manually installed* packages being re-installed being part fo the QA-test...)  Alas this isn't as useful for server installs; but I'm a desktop user & QA-test desktop installs.

Comment: For certain packages, like Microsoft’s SQL Server, you *really* don’t want to deviate from the documented path. There will be a lot of frustration when an update obliterates a library and brings that database engine down. If you want to use the latest release with software that demands specific versions of an OS, use either a VM or a Docker container. This will ensure you can continue to update your system without affecting the core tools you need.

Comment: 20.04 *is* the latest *LTS* release.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do older repositories no longer work with newer Ubuntu version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/456990/do-older-repositories-no-longer-work-with-newer-ubuntu-version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were super-easy and convenient to install a wrong-version deb package, everybody would do it. Your application would be supported on all releases of Ubuntu.

But it's not.

It can be very, very hard in some circumstances to install a wrong-version deb package. You're essentially asking "*Can I install this airplane engine into my automobile?*" If you need to ask the question, it's unlikely that you have the skills to successfully accomplish the task anyway.

It is unlikely that you can successfully install and run your application on the wrong release of Ubuntu. However, it's free to *try*. So go ahead and try. But be prepared with another plan if it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Some packages for different reasons needs to be updated to support new ubuntu version, but, you can probe downloading the deb package o adding the library repository to your

```
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/
```

And trying to install it, however, It may be dangerous because you going to introduce packages of another ubuntu version, maybe you need to think about install or use always LTS version, for later.